# Parameters vs Specialized functions

Tags: python, inheritance, methods

Trying to figure out which structure is cleaner between using a specialized function or using parameters to accomplish the same thing (see code example below).

Essentially, I can reduce the number of abstract methods in my interface by adding parameters (as in the `BufferParameter` case). If the methods themselves got too big (in terms of parameters and/or lines of code), then I'd swap over to explicit functions (as in `BufferMethod` case).

Is my logic sound here, or should I always prefer the `BufferMethod` case?

```
class BufferBase(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def clear(self):
        pass

    def clearall(self):
        """Only used in the `BufferMethod` class."""
        pass

class BufferParameter(BufferBase):
def clear(self, buffer_idx='all'):
    """Accepts either a buffer integer index or the string 'all'."""
    if buffer_idx == "all":
        for buff in self.buffers:
            buff.clear()
        return

    self.buffers[buffer_idx].clear()

class BufferMethod(BufferBase):
    def clear(self, buffer_idx):
        self.buffers[buffer_idx].clear()

    def clearall(self):
        for buff in self.buffers:
            buff.clear()
```

Examples of use:

```
bp = BufferParameter()
bm = BufferMethod()

for b in bp.buffers:
    b.write('foo')

for b in bm.buffers:
    b.write('foo')

bm.append('bar', buffer_idx=6)
bp.append('bar', buffer_idx=6)

print(bm.read(buffer_idx=6))
print(bp.read(buffer_idx=6))

print(bm.read(buffer_idx='all'))
print(bp.readall())

bm.clear('all')
bp.clearall()
```

Comment: As a sidenote - this applies to nearly every method in the base class, so either I have twice as many methods or each method has a special parameter.

Comment: It's hard to tell right now. Can you post some sample code how these classes would be used? As with any question about the public interface of a class, knowing how the objects get used is essential.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I've added an example of use to the question. Hope that helps clarify!

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer the BufferMethod approach over the BufferParameter approach.

Methods should ideally do only one thing.  Here, you are implementing two very different behaviors:  clearing one particular buffer by index, and clearing *all* buffers.  It's clearer and cleaner to have separate methods for them.

Comment: I completely agree with the "one thing" approach (thank you Uncle Bob), but I didn't want to be dogmatic about it, especially given the fact that they're both inheriting from an interface which may not have a `clearall` method for each subclass in the future.